# How to get a list of name disambiguations that occur using biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, apa-style

How can I get a list of disambiguations that have occurred in my document? I am using biber and biblatex with apa style. I have been troubleshooting these situations in my thesis because I had a lot of bibliography entries like

```
Smith, A
Smith, A.
Smith, A B
Smith, A. B.
```

where each Smith is in fact the same person.

Rather than just turn it off with `uniquename=false` I would like to fix these case-by-case. It would be very useful to get a list so I can go through and check them.

I have found information about why disambiguations occur, how to fix entries, how to turn it off, etc. But I have not seen anyone explain how to list the occurrences. I couldn't find any relevant option in the biblatex manual.

The below minimum working example produces

[image: mwe]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,uniquename=full]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Example_Article_1,
    Title                    = {Title 1},
    Author                   = {Smith, A.},
    Year                     = {2012},
    Month                    = {Oct},
    Number                   = {1},
    Pages                    = {42},
    Volume                   = {10},
    Journal                  = {Example Journal},
}

@Article{Example_Article_2,
    Title                    = {Title 2},
    Author                   = {Smith, A. B.},
    Year                     = {2012},
    Month                    = {Oct},
    Number                   = {1},
    Pages                    = {42},
    Volume                   = {10},
    Journal                  = {Example Journal},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\parencite{Example_Article_1}
\parencite{Example_Article_2}

\textcite{Example_Article_1}
\textcite{Example_Article_2}

\printbibliography[title=References]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should give a bit more information on your setup and how the disambiguated entries look in the `.bib` file. For example with the standard settings `\usepackage[uniquename=full,style=apa]{biblatex}` I get output like `Smith, A. [A.]` and `Smith, A. B. [A B]` which means you can just search for `[` or `]` in the pdf output to find all disambiguated entries.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you I have included a MWE. I don't see the square brackets though. I suppose there might be an option of biblatex that would let you inject some searchable phrase or symbol?

Comment: For this example no disambiguation is performed, because "Smith, A." and "Smith, A. B." are already different in the regular APA output format "Family name, Initials". Add in another paper with `author = {Smith, Anna}` for example to see the actual disambiguation being done, including `[]` in the output.

Comment: In any case, I see two possible solutions: either use a bibliography management tool like [BibTool](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtool) (or maybe Zotero or Mendeley or something) to automatically normalize auhtor names by stripping second initials etc, or go through the reference list in your thesis manually and identify the problematic entries. I understand you probably have hundreds of references but they are most likely alphabetized so a linear pass would be sufficient to spot all issues - and prevent possible overnormalization that occurs with automatic methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to list all the disambiguations that occur - it's all automatic and internal to `biber`. All it has to go on is the characters in the names in the `.bib` and it has no way of automatically deciding if a name is the same person as another variant of a name. However, you can normalise names yourself if you know what needs to be done by using sourcemaps and there are examples of exactly this situation with names on p. 208 of the current `biblatex` manual. This will dynamically change the data `biber` uses as it is read, without touching your `.bib`. Alternatively, you can do the same in `biber`'s "tool mode" (`--tool` option) to output a materialised version of the changed, just like with `bibtool` but more flexibly in several ways.